# Why my model always return 0 val loss in Keras Tensorflow when trained on Google Colab?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, tf.keras

I'm trying to train an easy model on Colab, but it always returns 0 validation loss when using my own code by`!python train.py`. However, this code runs perfectly fine on my own computer. Does anyone know the reason?

```
Epoch 1/500
2020-06-17 19:53:31.689547: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2020-06-17 19:53:31.889892: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
47/47 - 7s - loss: 52.6930 - mse: 2876.5457 - mae: 52.5915 - val_loss: 0.1029 - val_mse: 0.0000e+00 - val_mae: 0.0000e+00
```

The code for training:

```
    def build_model(self):
        new_model = self.base_model

        opt = Adam(lr=self.lr)
        new_model.compile(loss='mae',
                          optimizer=opt,
                          metrics=['mse', 'mae'])

        return new_model

    def train(self, base_epochs=500,
              save_model=False, save_path=None, cal_time=True):
        model = self.build_model()

        early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',
                                       patience=50,
                                       mode='min')
        save_best = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=save_file,
                                    monitor='val_loss',
                                    save_best_only=True,
                                    mode='min')
        cp_callback = [early_stopping, save_best]

        history = model.fit(
            x=self.standardize(self.train_data),
            y=self.train_labels,
            batch_size=self.batch_size,
            epochs=base_epochs,
            verbose=2,
            callbacks=cp_callback,
            validation_data=[self.standardize(self.val_data), self.val_labels],
        )
        return history
```

I also wrote code to check the image data.

```
    def check_data(self):
        data_name = ['Train Data', 'Train Labels', 'Validation Data', 'Validation Labels']
        for i, data in enumerate([self.train_data, self.train_labels, self.val_data, self.val_labels]):
            print('{0:<20}:  shape-{1:<20} type--{2}' \
                  .format(data_name[i], str(data.shape), data.dtype))
```

And here's the information about the data, they're all numpy arrays:

```
Train Data          :  shape-(3000, 224, 224, 1)  type--float32
Train Labels        :  shape-(3000, 2)            type--float64
Validation Data     :  shape-(200, 224, 224, 1)   type--float32
Validation Labels   :  shape-(200, 2)             type--float64
```

Comment: What do you mean it does not recognize the validation data? What evidence do you have of it?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy val_loss: 0.1029 - val_mse: 0.0000e+00 - val_mae: 0.0000e+00, all this val metrics are 0 in each epoch. But if I run it on  my own laptop these metrics are shown with reasonable values.

Comment: That does not mean "not recognizing you validation data", it could be that your code results the wrong validation data, there are too many things that can fail, so you should edit your question and include some relevant code, we cannot say much with only the fit call

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Sorry for my negligence and inappropriate problem description. I've edited the question and add more information about the data. Could you take a look at it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I finally find the problem:

I'm passing a list to `validation_data=`, which should be a tuple according to the official website.

It should be:

```
history = model.fit(
    x=self.standardize(self.train_data),
    y=self.train_labels,
    batch_size=self.batch_size,
    epochs=base_epochs,
    verbose=2,
    callbacks=cp_callback,
    validation_data=(self.standardize(self.val_data), self.val_labels),
)
```